# Listnode problem implementing the count occurrences method (recursive)

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, implementation

hello guys im trying to implement ListNode and im having problem with those both methods

- `contains(E data)` which takes a generic object and check for its existence in the list.
- `countIf(E data)`which takes a generic object and checks for its occurrences in a ListNode.

I know that it could be implemented in an iterative approach but I want to exercise recursive so please tell me what im doing wrong:

```
public class ListNode2<E> {

    public E data;

    public ListNode2<E> next;

    public ListNode2(){
        this.data=null;
        this.next=null;
    }
    public ListNode2(E data, ListNode2<E> n) {
        this.data = data;
        next= n;
    }

    public ListNode2(E data) {
        this.data = data;
        next=null;
    }

    public E getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public ListNode2<E> getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    public ListNode2<E> addFirst(E data) {
        return new ListNode2<>(data, this);
    }
    public boolean contains(E data){

        if ( data ==null && this.getData()==null )
            return true;

        if (data!=null && (data.equals(this.getData())))
            return true;

        if (this.next==null)//remove the next and we have nullpointer exception but right results :( 
            return false;

        return this.getNext().contains(data);
    }    

    public int countIf(E data) {
        //i was missing the getNext() but now i get for the first element zero
        if(this.getNext()==null)
            return 0;

        if (data ==null && this.getData() == null )
            return 1+ getNext().countIf(data);

        if ( data!= null && (data.equals(this.getData())) )
            return 1 + getNext().countIf(data);



        return getNext().countIf(data);
    }

    public int size() {
        if (getNext() == null) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 1 + getNext().size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data + " ";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ListNode2<Integer> list = null; // Leere Liste.
        list = new ListNode2<Integer>(1); // ergibt 1.
        list = list.addFirst(2);
        list = list.addFirst(3);
        list = list.addFirst(4);
        int size = list.size();

        System.out.println(size);

        System.out.println("countif 1 "+ list.countIf(1));//this gives 0 why??
        System.out.println("countif 2 "+ list.countIf(2));
        System.out.println("countif 3 "+ list.countIf(3));
        System.out.println("countif 5 "+ list.countIf(5));
        System.out.println("countif null "+ list.countIf(null));
        System.out.println("countif 7 "+ list.countIf(7));
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong in the countIf method? i cant seem to figure it out?

edit: 
corrected the contains method as suggested by the User: **Ole V.V.** .
but applying the same hint on the `countIF()` : it looks like this

```
    public int countIf(E data) {

    if (data!= null && (data.equals(this.getData())) )
        return 1 + getNext().countIf(data);//this line is the 74

    if ( data ==null && this.getData() == null )
        return 1+ getNext().countIf(data);

    if(this.getNext()==null)
        return 0;


    return getNext().countIf(data);   //this line is the 83 
}
```

with the output:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.hsmannheim.inf.pr2.ads.ListNode2.countIf(ListNode2.java:74)
    at de.hsmannheim.inf.pr2.ads.ListNode2.countIf(ListNode2.java:83)
    at de.hsmannheim.inf.pr2.ads.ListNode2.countIf(ListNode2.java:83)
    at de.hsmannheim.inf.pr2.ads.ListNode2.countIf(ListNode2.java:83)
    at de.hsmannheim.inf.pr2.ads.ListNode2.main(ListNode2.java:126)
/home/pi/.cache/netbeans/11.0/executor-snippets/run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/pi/.cache/netbeans/11.0/executor-snippets/run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `countIf` function does not take into account the value of the first element.
You can correct it in the following way:

```java
public int countIf(E data)
{
  boolean isDataEq = Objects.equals(data, this.data);

  if(getNext() == null)
  {
    return isDataEq ? 1 : 0;
  }

  int nextCount = getNext().countIf(data);
  return isDataEq ? 1 + nextCount : nextCount;
}
```

And you can simplify your `contains` function in the following way:

```
public boolean contains(E data)
{
  if (Objects.equals(data, this.data)) return true;
  if (next==null) return false;
  return next.contains(data);
}
```

Comment: thank you sir for suggesting this great solution but I would like to know how to repair my code without replacing it with your code because I'm a cs student and I do coding in my spare time to get better. so its quite interesting for me to know other approaches as well as knowing how to correct my mistakes. so do you know how to adjust my code to work perfectly like yours because I couldn't figure that out? thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is `if(this.getNext()==null) return 0;`, as I said. You should correct it like this `if(this.getNext()==null) return Objects.equals(data, this.data) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: And if you know that both compared arguments can be null, I would suggest you to use `Objects.equals`. It will allow you to be more brevity.

Comment: omg, now I see. so we add the check if we reach the last element and the pre-last and the last are the same we return 1 instead of 0 that's brilliant!. but I want to punch myself in the face hahaha...how didnt i manage to figure it out..thanks alot man.

Comment: actually I didn't know that such thing as ``Object.equals`` until you submitted it in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It’s about the order of the checks you are performing.

```
    public boolean contains(E data){

        if (this.next==null)//remove the next and we have nullpointer exception but right results :( add the 
            return false;

        if ( data ==null && this.getData()==null )
            return true;

        if (data!=null && (data.equals(this.getData())))
            return true;

        return this.getNext().contains(data);
    }
```

Now if the data element sought after is in the last node, what happens? First you check whether `next` is `null`. It is. So you return `false`. You never get around to discovering that the data is right in the same node.

Instead you need to put the `null` check after the two checks on the content (but still before the `return` statement containing the recursive call, of course).

**EDIT:** The case of `countIf()` is similar but more complicated. Again you first need to test whether the data is the one searched for and “count” it if it is, obtaining either 0 or 1. Then test whether `next` or `getNext()` is `null`. If it is, return the count obtained. In the end you need to add the obtained count from before to the result of the recursive call.

Nice code, by the way.

Comment: i figure out what was the cause of the problems in the ``countIf()`` method but I'm still getting zero for the first element as if it wasn't there

Comment: I’m chasing a moving target here since there are a number of edits to your question. I don’t know which version to answer, nor whether you will make further edits that may render my answer invalid. I still believe that my answer was to the point at some point, also with respect to `countIf()`. If you have edited that method and still don’t understand why it gives an incorrect result, please ask a new question. You may link to your new question from here, and then if I have a good opportunity for checking, I will.

Comment: Sir in the countif() method i just changed the first if clause it was this==null and i made it this.getNext()==null nothing. I didnt even change the position of the if clause.

Comment: I can post another question but i dont like to spam in stack overflow and if i asked 2 questions of the same topic its is not quite good for the good people like you who are willing to help. But if there any way that i would be able to tag you from the other post then i would delete this and post another then i would tag you if no one answered :)

Comment: In your `countIf` method you still have an order of checks that is similar to the order you had in `contains` from the outset. That order gave you the problem in `contains`. And it is still giving you the problem in `countIf`. Please trust in yourself. You can solve it in a way that is similar to how you solved it in `contains()`.

Comment: No, on Stack Overflow there isn’t a way to tag a person under a question or answer where that person hasn’t already posted a comment. I would consider it poor style to delete a question where someone has already put an honest effort into writing a helpful answer.

Comment: sir I don't want to delete the answer because I appreciate your efforts of putting time to find the error in the code neither wanted to spam anyone. your efforts are most appreciated :)